# Capture entire substring using regex if there is a match on a number

Tags: r, regex

I have been unable to find the answer to this specific question, I am using R to clean some survey data.

I have some messy survey data with question names as columns, that sometimes include a number and sometimes don't. When they include a number, it will often contain some subcharacters as well indicating the question. Example, I have this vector:

```
questions <- c(
"1 question 1 what do you think?",
"1.a. question 1a further details on what you think",
"Please explain",
"2 question 2 what is your motivation",
"2.a. further details",
"2.b. even further details",
"Please explain")
```

I want to extract the substrings that contain numbers, and return no results if there is no such match. Desired result (using R)

```
"1"
"1.a."
NA
"2"
"2.a."
"2.b."
NA
```

I know I can capture the first number, using

```
 stri_extract_first_regex(questions, "[0-9]+")
```

But I am at a loss how to modify it to capture the whole string until the first whitespace if it finds a match using this pattern.

Comment: Do you mean like `\d+(?:\.[a-z]\.)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example data you might use:

`[0-9]+(?:\.[a-z]\.)?`

That will match:

- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.[a-z]\.` Match a dot, lowercase character and a dot
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional

For example:

```
questions <- c(
"1 question 1 what do you think?",
"1.a. question 1a further details on what you think",
"Please explain",
"2 question 2 what is your motivation",
"2.a. further details",
"2.b. even further details",
"Please explain")

print(stri_extract_first_regex(questions, "[0-9]+(?:\\.[a-z]\\.)?"))

# [1] "1"    "1.a." NA     "2"    "2.a." "2.b." NA
```

Comment: Hello, just a question, is there a way to modify this to only look at the beginning of a string (say, the first 5 characters)? I'm having trouble with some questions that have no numerical indicator (like the 'Please explain" in my example)contain numbers inside of them, which are not in fact the question number.

Comment: @JohnHekman You can use an anchor to assert the start of the string `^[0-9]+(?:\\.[a-z]\\.)?` See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vyCgs8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
hasnumber <- grepl("[0-9]+",questions)
firstspaces <- sapply(gregexpr(" ", questions), function(x) x[[1]])
res <- ifelse(hasnumber, substr(questions,1,firstspaces-1), NA)
> res
[1] "1"    "1.a." NA     "2"    "2.a." "2.b." NA
```

The most difficult part I guess is to define where are the first spaces in each question, which could be done with loops or here `sapply`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
questions <- sub("^(\\d+(?:\\.[a-z0-9]+)*\\.?).*|.*", "\\1", questions)
questions[questions==""] <- NA
questions
# => [1] "1"    "1.a." NA     "2"    "2.a." "2.b." NA
```

The `^(\\d+(?:\\.[a-z0-9]+)*\\.?).*|.*` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\\d+(?:\\.[a-z0-9]+)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\\.[a-z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\\.` - a dot
    - `[a-z0-9]+` - 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters or digits
  - `\\.?`  - an optional dot
- `.*` - any 0+ chars to the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `.*` - the whole string.

Replaces with the contents of Group 1. If the second alternative matches, the result is an empty string, `questions[questions==""] <- NA` replaces these elements with `NA`s.